# Is it secured to check if user is logged in with cookies?

Tags: php, security

On a website I am developing I am currently checking if a user is logged in if it's cookies are set. The thing is I'm using these information for some request on the database and allow him to do some tasks on the website. Though, it came to my mind that if the user edit its cookies, he might be able to be someone else (editing it's username/id). So, is there a way to secure it or do I have to use sessions ?

Comment: Take a lookie at discomatt's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427817/is-hashing-the-username-in-a-cookie-safe-enough-for-a-persistent-login-mechanism

Comment: @ExplosionPills : sessions are handled on the server though, seems safer but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use cookies. You just need to make sure that the cookie provides data you can use to authenticate the user, and not a token that means the user *is* authenticated.

Bad cookie:

```
username=foo,logged_in=true
```

Good cookie:

```
token=uifhjrjf4093jf3904j90j390kf934j8438j0493jf9034
```

And then compare the authentication data against a datastore on the server.

> Do I have to use sessions?

Sessions are a way to store temporary about a user (who may or may not be authenticated). They are a quick and easy way to solve part of the problem and not something that should cause reactions of *Do I **have** to? :(*.

Most session libraries use cookies to store the token that links the collection of data associated with a session to the browser to which the session belongs.

Comment: for a example, using a key (different from the id) that other people can't know would be okay ?

Comment: You need to make sure the cookie value is not predictable in any way.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is give a random hash in a cookie, then have point it to a database table in which I store the full browser string, a time to live, a last access time, the username and the hashed password (for comparison in case the user changes passwords because he was compromised, this will invalidate every other sessions except the one that changed his password).

Comment: Couldn't you invalidate other sessions by just deleting them from your database table?

Comment: It would work too, I guess. Although in the case I'm pointing at I'm not using this only for users, but for other things like current language and other session informations.

Comment: Though you have to check the database at every access right ? I can't do that.

Comment: Why not? You already have to have to check the user's validity.

Comment: Languages and other information would be better stored in your user table, then joined based on session info. Like, `users: user_id, language, etc`, `session: session_id, user_id, last_access`.

Comment: I usually allow non-loggedin users to be able to change language and I usually keep the same language after loging-out, but that's your choice, I guess. (And it's not really related to the question directly)

Comment: @arthurquerou If you can live with a maximum of 1 session per users, then you can always just add a "sessionid" and a "browser" row in your users tables. I would recommend against that though.